# CompletableFuture.allOf meaning

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future

Do I understand it well, that when I use

```
CompletableFuture.allOf("array of CompletableFuture")
                 .runAsync(()-> { "piece of code" });
```

first I have to wait until the array of CF are all done , and than the Runnable "piece of code" is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CompletableFuture.allOf static method allows to wait for completion of all of the Futures provided as a var-arg.

For example

```
CompletableFuture<String> future1  
  = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "Hello");
CompletableFuture<String> future2  
  = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "Beautiful");
CompletableFuture<String> future3  
  = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "World");

CompletableFuture<Void> combinedFuture 
  = CompletableFuture.allOf(future1, future2, future3);
```

Comment: Thanks. So first future1-3 must finish and then if I run for example combinedFuture.runAsync(()->{'some code'}; - the 'some code' will run?

Comment: Exactly. That's it

Answer (score 2):

That is *explicit* in the documentation:

> Returns a new CompletableFuture that is completed when **all** of the given CompletableFutures complet